# The minimum PHP version required for this plugin is 5.6.0. You are running 5.3.29

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am trying to add a plugin to my divi theme, but it is giving me the error: The minimum PHP version required for this plugin is 5.6.0. You are running 5.3.29.

What does that mean? Where would I go to update the PHP? I am using Stable host, Wordpress, Divi theme and Strip is the plugin that I am trying to install
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KWWy.png)

Comment: It means precisely what it says. You need 5.6.0 for the plugin and you are running 5.3.29. What part of that is causing you difficulty? Google can tell you where to download it; asking here is off-topic. We're not link finders.

Comment: Your host does not have PHP 5.6 installed, they are still using an older version (5.3).  You need to ask your host if they have the newer version available, or if they can install it, *or* move to a new host.

Comment: I guess my question is that the php needs to updated on stable host, not on wordpress

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.3 reached end of life awhile ago and should not be used in production environment.

http://php.net/supported-versions.php

If your host does not provide PHP updates, I would re-consider your hosting options as this is a major red flag. You're site is not secure and could be easily compromised.

Outdated PHP and Wordpress sites are one of the most common hacks.

As of writing, PHP 5.6 is the only 5.x release still receiving security patches and will do until the end of 2018. (Note, that PHP 7.0 also ends on this, so I am advising that you move from 5.6 and by the end of next year, to 7.1 or 7.2)

I would suggest the following.

1. FTP into your site, 
   take a backup of `wp-content` - This is your site, the other directories are Wordpress Core.
2. take a backup of `wp-config.php` - This is your configuration to the DB.
3. Login to your hosts cPanel and navigate to phpMyadmin /Database panel and then `export` the the database to your machine along with the `wp-content` and `wp-config.php`. You now have your Wordpress backed up, so if something happens after this point, you can put these files back in place.
4. Upgrade your Wordpress Plugins 1 by 1. - do this and check if the site crashes/ gives errors on pages where a plugin is being used. (CF7 on Contact Us page, etc).
5. All good? great, now update Wordpress if you have any, latest is 4.7.3 with 4.7.4 coming soon. Keep your wordpress up to date!
6. Finally, if this is all good. Demand that your host gets their act together and to upgrade the PHP version to 5.6. And that you are ready to test it. (if they refuse, then take your 3 main files we backedup and move to another host, there is no excuse for no updating PHP from such a old version).
7. Once this is done, check through the site to see if there is any more issues. If any, let the host know that X plugin is no longer working, and let the plugin developer know by the Support forms on Wordpress Plugins repo (where you downloaded it). If the plugin is over a year without an update, consider getting rid of it/replace, the developer has abandoned it.
8. Have a beer

Hope this was helpful, Cheers